# Why is django giving error: no module named django.core?

Tags: python, windows, django, django-admin

I get the error in question when I attempt to create a project. I followed the instructions found at [how to install python an django in windows vista](http://i.justrealized.com/2008/04/08/how-to-install-python-and-django-in-windows-vista/).

Comment: What is your PYTHONPATH set to?  What is in your `C:\pythonx.x\Lib` directory?  Also, update your question with the value of `sys.path`.

Comment: Where would I find PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also make sure that you have permission to access all of django's files.  I've seen these kinds of errors happen because of permissions issues before.

**EDIT**:  I haven't tried it out, but there's a link on that page to [Instant Django](http://www.instantdjango.com/), which looks like a pretty easy to set up.

Comment: Word! That Instant Django worked like a charm. I usually shy away from tools that set a bunch of configurations I might need to know how to troubleshoot, but this Instant Django looked clean and professional, and I was about to pull my hair out lol. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can get around this problem by providing the full path to your django-admin.py file

```
python c:\python25\scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you don't have Django on your Python path. To test, quickly fire up Python and run:

```
>>> import django
```

If that fails, it's just a matter of getting Django onto your Python path. Either you set the environment variable, or you move django into your `python2x/Lib/site-packages` directory. If it does work, try importing `core`. If that fails there, then something is probably wrong with your Django install.

Comment: I tried the following:
>>> import django
>>> import django.core

both worked, but I still can't run:
django-admin.py startproject my_django_project

I still get the error. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From your command line (`cmd`) run "ftype Python.File" and make sure that your .py files are being executed by the correct version/installation of Python.

It's possible another application has surreptitiously changed this under the hood.